# QT push button and a python lambda function

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, designer, maya

I'm just trying to create a UI for my script in maya/py using QT Designer.

The problem is that I want to use a lambda expression as a command for my buttons
by adding a dynamic property with the type set to string, property name set to "+command" 
and `lambda x: print('fobar!')` as the value.

But running the code back in Maya using the loadUI Python command gives me a syntax error.

It actually loads the UI but the button's function doesn't work!

Comment: How should anyone be able to help w/o code?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
button_name.clicked.connect(lambda : print('foobar'))
```